# How to make Polymer/Meteor-polymer package work with Meteor?

Tags: meteor, polymer, polymer-1.0

I've tried

- to install Polymer manually directly from polymer-project web site

> bower install PolymerElements/paper-menu # installs polymer core and web polyfills too

**template.html**

```
<template name="common">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
    <paper-menu>
        <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
        <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</template>
```

it just renders the menu as plain text "item 1 item 2".

Also, it prints it **twice**, like the **import** was just an "add to template".

- Tried with boxxa:polymer meteor package

> meteor add boxxa:polymer-paper # automatically installs polymer-core too
>
> meteor run

After that I get an error which tells me a proper version of Polymer can't be found (detailed issue open here: https://github.com/boxxa/meteor-polymer-paper/issues/4 )

So, I can't figure out how to use Polymer's paper-elements in my Meteor app. I intend to use Polymer 1.0.0 if possible.